# Prevent FlatList scrolling when new items are added

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

I have an inverted vertical `FlatList` in my chat app, which shows the newest message at the bottom and the oldest message at the top (like all other chat applications)
The problem is when I want to add new messages to the bottom of my list, `FlatList` automatically jumps to the bottom end of the list!
All I need is to prevent scrolling in this situation

Here is my `FlatList`:

```
<FlatList
  inverted
  style={{flex: 1}}
  data={this.state.data}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
/>
```

And here is the code to add the newest messages to the list

```
const data = [ ...newMessages, ...this.state.data ];
this.setState({ data });
```

Comment: @Tim I tried to clarify my problem. please check again

Comment: Did you ever come around to solve this issue?

Comment: @RyanPergent unfortunately not. Also I've opened an issue on github for this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25239

Comment: what is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Your case look simple but you are adding new message at top then reverse it to bottom last position using `inverted` flag

Could remove `inverted` flag and add new item at last simply `const data = [...this.state.data, ...newMessages];`

```
<FlatList
  style={{flex: 1}}
  data={this.state.data}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
/>

const data = [...this.state.data, ...newMessages];
this.setState({ data });
```

I hope this will work

Comment: I need to add new items in both side of `FlatList` as I mention in my question: **which shows newest message in bottom and oldest message in top (likes all other chat applications)**

Answer (score 0):

**Put this in the view**

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
      ref={ref => {
        this.flatListRef = ref;
      }}
      initialScrollIndex={0}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      extraData={this.state.refresh}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => {
        // animation={animation}
        return (
          <ListItem
            inAnimation={inAnimation}
            outAnimation={outAnimation}
            duration={duration}
            easing={easing}
            isDeleted={item._isDeleted}
            id={item.id}
            item={item}
          />
        );
      }}
    `/>`
```

**Run this in a function**

```
this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({
       animated: true,
       index: nextProps.indexScroll})

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onViewableItemsChanged and scrollToIndex together to keep the viewableItems as per previous state.

```
const flatListRef = React.useRef();
const startIndexRef = React.useRef(0);
  
const handleListChange = () => {
  // ...otherlogic

  if (haseAddedToStart)
    flatListRef.current?.scrollToIndex({
      index: startIndexRef.current + 1,
      animated: false,
    });      
};

const onViewableItemsChanged = React.useCallback(({ viewableItems }) => {
  startIndexRef.current = viewableItems[0].index;
}, []);
```

Extra props to be added to Flat List are ref and onViewableItemsChanged

```
 <FlatList              
          ref={flatListRef}
          onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
          // ...otherProps
        />
```

onViewableItemsChanged should come with useCallback, as changes to list would cause error.

It will scroll smaller than item height if the first item is half visible.

A more accurate result should be achievable via onScrollEndDrag and onMomentumScrollEnd but it needs calculating items height.

Answer (score -1):

You should use a workaround to achieve this. If you check the documentation for FlatList (which extends the props of ScrollView), you'll see that all you need to do is set the scrollEnabled prop to false to disable scrolling. How and where you choose to do this will be up to you since you didn't really post a lot of code. A simple way to handle this would be to use state:

```
<FlatList
  ...
  scrollEnabled={this.state.scrollEnabled}
/>
```

In your case you could change the state when the new data is being loaded and change it back when it is rendered.

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25239#issuecomment-521194810) on Github about this case.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but this is not work and `FlatList` still scrolls down automatically after adding new items even if `scrollEnabled` sets to `false`